# PHP regex to format json string without quotes

Tags: php, json, regex, quotes

I have a string of json objects I need to json_decode but the json format is not valid because it doesn't have double quotes (or any quote). And some texts have commas what makes it more difficult to format as json.

This is the string I get:

`[{2:,0:1,1:Rodapi\u00e9s 1-a, 2-a, bloque 6}]`

This is the format I need to be a valid JSON:

`[{"2":"","0":"1","1":"Rodapi\u00e9s 1-a, 2-a, bloque 6"}]`

I have a code to add strings but doesn't work with texts containing commas:

```
$str = str_replace('{', '{"', $str);
$str = str_replace(':', '":"', $str);
$str = str_replace(',', '","', $str);
$str = str_replace('}', '"}', $str);
$str = str_replace('}","{', '},{', $str);
```

This is what I get:

`[{"2":"","0":"1","1":"Rodapi\u00e9s 1-a"," 2-a"," bloque 6"}]`

Comment: Did you intend for us to understand that a comma within a "text" always has a space behind it, and a normal JSON separator comma not?

Comment: Could you please confirm that you cannot change how this invalid JSON string is generated, and that you have tried to contact the creator, but couldn't contact them?

Comment: `the json format is not valid`...which means that `I have a string of json objects` is not true. `I have a string` would be more accurate. Or `I have a string which looks a bit like json`, perhaps.

Comment: The problem is strings can always include characters that can be valid JSON token (e.g. `,`, `{`). It would be really hard to determine when to end a string quote.

Comment: Can text values include a `:` or `}`?

Comment: Also, can the object be nested, or is it just a single level as shown in your example data?

Comment: For your sample [replace `(\d+):((?:[^,\d}\]]+|,(?!\h*\d+:)|\d+(?!:))*)` with `"$1":"$2"`](https://regex101.com/r/8oagcB/1) would work ([PHP demo](https://tio.run/##FY69CoMwGAD3PMXXICTRFIxDoZ8trh2lq7HFn1ALgqnWqeqrp3E5OG4521nnLll@ywkJpu8IV2DFL0EZo5IK70Nb2bee49icJ1DHSkKyo@6Hz2zgtJYsJcQ03QB2NK/naGxfNYazjes2Esh5hsVD6nbVZRktkmcH3YU@oVg8vaIQodiYBEYDRZEGCfWyr4jUuT8)).

Comment: Hi Nick Its an array of objects, in the example there is only one object but could be more, and the texts could contain `:` but is more unusual, if someone can help with this would be great but the regex for texts with commas its ok for what I need with more urgency

Comment: Fix the creation of the STRING to make it JSON dont fudge it after the fact, you will almost definitely keep finding edge cases that break your code

Comment: Pure regex will not be enough. You will need to write your own parser that can understand the current context and provide fallbacks. Additionally here are ambiguous edge cases like `[one, two]`.

Comment: My impression is that this is not a properly designed data format but some data dump (maybe a log file) that was never meant to be machine-readable. If that's the case, you need to account for potentially incoherent values, typically caused by actual data containing brackets, quotes, colons, commas... Shaping it to feed a JSON parser may not be the best solution if those cases are common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your keys are numeric, then the following regex should meet your needs:

```
(?<=[{,])\s*(\d+)\s*:(.*?)(?=}|,\s*\d+\s*:)
```

It matches:

- `(?<=[{,])` : lookbehind for `{` or `,`
- `\s*(\d+)\s*:` : a numeric key, possibly surrounded by spaces, captured in group 1
- `(.*?)` : a minimal number of characters, captured in group 2, subject to the following lookahead
- `(?=}|,\s*\d+\s*:)` : a lookahead for either a `}` or a comma followed by a numeric key value

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rxxmaD/1)

In PHP:

```php
$str = '[{2:,0:1,1:Rodapi\u00e9s 1-a, 2-a, bloque 6},
{4:x, y, z,0 :111, 3:some random text},{5:a45:bc,def}]';

$str = preg_replace('/(?<=[{,])\s*(\d+)\s*:(.*?)(?=}|,\s*\d+\s*:)/', '"$1":"$2"', $str);

$obj = json_decode($str);
print_r($obj);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [2] => 
            [0] => 1
            [1] => Rodapiés 1-a, 2-a, bloque 6
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [4] => x, y, z
            [0] => 111
            [3] => some random text
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [5] => a45:bc,def
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gsOc6)

Answer (score 2):

Replace numeric keys with string keys

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\d+):/', '"$1":', $str);
```

Add double quotes around values

```
$str = preg_replace('/(":)(.*?)(,"|})/', '$1"$2"$3', $str);
```